# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.

Tags: c#, console, smtpclient

namespace mailcode
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SendEmailToInformCustomerForNewOrderMessage();
        }

```
    public static void SendEmailToInformCustomerForNewOrderMessage()
    {           
        try
        {
            SendMail();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Write(CreateExceptionString(ex));
        }
    }

    public static void SendMail()
    {

        try
        {
            // Gmail Address from where you send the mail      
            dynamic fromAddress = "frommail@gmail.com";
            // any address where the email will be sending
            dynamic toAddress = "tomail@gmail.com";

            //Password of your gmail address
            const string fromPassword = "password";
            // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
            string subject = "test mail code";
            string body = "From: " + "Puneet";
            body += "Email: " + "fromemail@gmail.com";
            body += "Subject: " + "Test email code";
            body += "Question: " + "test question";
            // smtp settings
            dynamic smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            if (true)
            {
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Timeout = 20000;
            }
            // Passing values to smtp object
            dynamic message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Write(CreateExceptionString(ex));
        }
    }

    public static string CreateExceptionString(Exception e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        CreateExceptionString(sb, e, string.Empty);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static void CreateExceptionString(StringBuilder sb, Exception e, string indent)
    {
        if (indent == null)
        {
            indent = string.Empty;
        }
        else if (indent.Length > 0)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}Inner ", indent);
        }

        sb.AppendFormat("Exception Found:" + "& vbLf &" + "{0}Type: {1}", indent, e.GetType().FullName);
        sb.AppendFormat("& vbLf &" + "{0}Message: {1}", indent, e.Message);
        sb.AppendFormat("& vbLf &" + "{0}Source: {1}", indent, e.Source);
        sb.AppendFormat("& vbLf &" + "{0}Stacktrace: {1}", indent, e.StackTrace);

        if (e.InnerException != null)
        {
            sb.Append("& vbLf &");
            CreateExceptionString(sb, e.InnerException, indent + "  ");
        }
    }

    public sealed class Logger
    {

        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here    
        public static void Write(string value)
        {
            StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"exceptionfile.txt");
            writetext.WriteLine(value);
            writetext.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

> I have an error occur in this test c# console application. please help me and fixed this. error

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code:

You need to swap these two lines:

```
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

To this:

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
```

Otherwise authentication fails.

Also the gmail SMTP server employs flood control systems which prevent you from spamming it. If you perform too many sends or made too many unsuccessful attempts to connect it can ban your IP for a short period of time.

You should handle such cases in your code and try again later.